# Google Dataflow: create templates with runtime parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

In Data flow, I need to pass start Date and end date as runtime arguments and query bigquery for that date range and write output to day wise folders.

When we use ValueProvider, getStartDate().get() method is throwing  java.lang.RuntimeException: Not called from a runtime context. If I hardcode some value when getStartDate().get().isAccessible() is false, template is being generated but the runtime arguments are not reflecting in job. It is always running with the hardcoded value during template creation.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigQueryIO` takes a `ValueProvider` of the query. The easiest way to do this is to pass the query text as the runtime value.

`NestedValueProvider` could help you create the query string from another value provider, alas, `NestedValueProvider` only support one input `ValueProvider` at a time. So you could concatenate your start and end dates into a single value and then do the split.

Comment: Thank you very much!! NestedValueProvider is very helpful.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if google's documentation on Dataflow templates explains how and when to use RuntimeValueProvider, NestedValueProvider and StaticValueProvider etc. with some examples.

Comment: You can find google docs on runtime and nested value provider here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates